# Многопоточность в JavaFX. Not on FX application thread

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть поток

```java
Thread skillshowin = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            newskill.setStyle("visibility: true");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            Thread.interrupted();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            skill.setText("" + Integer.valueOf(skill.getText()) + 5);
            newskill.setStyle("visibility: false");
        }
    }
});
skillshowin.start();
```

Но мне выдает ошибку`Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5` при выполнении skill.setText

Comment: Странно, что у вас вообще поток создался! Поток создаётся при вызове метода `start()`, а не `run()`.

Comment: Я знаю, я потом увидел. Уже изменил, всё-равно не помогает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы изменять `UI` (пользовательский интерфейс) в других потоках в `JavaFX` необходимо использовать другие средства:

**`Platform.runLater()`**:

Вариант с лямбдой:

```java
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    //ваш код
});
```

Либо вариант с `Runnable`:

```java
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //ваш код
    }
});
```

А также `Service` и `Task`. `Service` обладает большими возможностями, чем обычный `Thread`. Изменение `UI` внутри `Task` не выбросит `Not on FX application thread`, однако внутри `Task` тоже нужно прописывать `Platform.runLater()`, иначе могут возникнуть всяческие ошибки.

```java
Service service = new Service() {
    @Override
    protected Task createTask() {
        return new Task() {
            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    //ваш код
                });
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
};
service.start();
```